# Kizala response time in attendance card is not accurate when mark attendance

Tags: time-and-attendance, kaizala, kaizala-action

Kizala response time in attendance card is not showing accurate time with mark attendance.

For instance, when I mark attendance at time 11: AM, it shows in the report 9:07 AM.

Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The time which you see in the Report is always in UTC.